# Python scrape dynamic filters javascript

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from this website https://www.bcb.gov.br/estatisticas/reporttxjuroshistorico

It contains 3 filters, each combination of them generates a table that I am trying to extact. My code (below) is running smoothly but extracts an inexistent table. How to find the right table? I look at the HTML source of the website " _ng_content-jar-c173" (commented out) but when replacing in my code an empty dataframe is generated instead.

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Setup Selenium WebDriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# URL of the webpage
url = 'https://www.bcb.gov.br/estatisticas/reporttxjuroshistorico'
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the initial page load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ng-select")))

# Options for each dropdown
segmento_option = "Pessoa Física"  # Example for one segmento option
modalidade_options = ["Aquisição de veículos - Pré-fixado", "Aquisição de outros bens - Pré-fixado"]
periodo_options = ["26/10/2023 a 01/11/2023", "25/10/2023 a 31/10/2023"]

# Function to select an option in ng-select using JavaScript
def select_ng_option_using_js(value, dropdown_index):
    script = f"""
    var select = document.getElementsByTagName('ng-select')[{dropdown_index}];
    var ngModel = select.getAttribute('ng-reflect-model');
    select.ngModel = '{value}';
    select.dispatchEvent(new Event('ngModelChange'));
    """
    driver.execute_script(script)

# Initialize a list to store all DataFrames
all_dataframes = []

# Loop through options for the selected segmento
for modalidade_option in modalidade_options:
    for periodo_option in periodo_options:
        # Change the value of ng-select elements
        select_ng_option_using_js(segmento_option, 0)  # Segmento
        select_ng_option_using_js(modalidade_option, 1)  # Modalidade
        select_ng_option_using_js(periodo_option, 2)  # Período

        # Wait for the table to update
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.table.table-striped")))

        # Extract the table
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table table-striped'})
        # #table = soup.find('table', {' _ng_content-jar-c173': True})

        # Extracting rows
        rows = []
        if table:
            for row in table.find('tbody').find_all('tr'):
                cells = row.find_all('td')
                row_data = [cell.text.strip() for cell in cells]
                rows.append(row_data)

            # Create a DataFrame for this table
            df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Position', 'Financial Institution', 'Monthly Rate', 'Annual Rate'])

            # Add new columns for filters
            df['Segment'] = segmento_option
            df['Modality'] = modalidade_option
            df['Period'] = periodo_option

            # Add the DataFrame to the list
            all_dataframes.append(df)

# Combine all DataFrames into a single DataFrame
combined_df = pd.concat(all_dataframes, ignore_index=True)

combined_df.to_csv('/interest_rates_combined.csv', index=False)
print(combined_df)

# Close the driver
driver.quit()
```

Comment: maybe first run without `--headless` to see what you really get in browser. And keep open browser so you could check in `DevTools` in browser what properties has `<table>`. Maybe server generate different values for different users and it may need to use different method to get table - i.e. it may need to get all tables and use index to get correct table - `list_with_all_tables[index]`

Comment: I tested your code and this table always has different attribute - `_ngcontent-ylx-c173`, `_ngcontent-eme-c173`, etc. So don't use this value for searching table. Or you may need to use `regex` to search attribute with `_ngcontent-` and `-c173` `. Eventually you can use function to test attributes.

Comment: I run your code (without `--headless`) and as for me your problem is not `find()` but only `select_ng_option_using_js()` - it doesn't change option in dropdown menu and it always display the same table.